# What time settings is referred for `extractor.history.start-time` and `extractor.history.end-time` in pipe configuration in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now trying to set up `pipe` configuration in Apache IoTDB, and I saw I need to set two time parameters, `extractor.history.start-time` and `extractor.history.end-time`. I want to know are these parameter values referring to the time of the data, or the time of the data arrival at IoTDB. If it is for the data arrival time, then how can I set up a possible delaying time interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `extractor.history.start-time` and `extractor.history.end-time` parameters of `pipe` in Apache IoTDB can be set to the time of the data itself, so you do not need to set any delaying time interval.